# get the lines one by one with pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, lines

I have a dictionary named cluster_ordre of dataframe, 
for example cluster_ordre['cluster0']:

```
                     cat  cluster0
7        Home Appliances  0.555528
6          Home & Living  0.086105
5        Health & Beauty  0.065635
9      Mobiles & Tablets  0.060538
11   Toys, Kids & Babies  0.055134
4   Consumer Electronics  0.042442
3    Computers & Laptops  0.040914
1                Cameras  0.034429
2   Clothes Shoes & Bags  0.023386
13               Watches  0.015138
8   Media, Games & Music  0.007444
12      Travel & Luggage  0.006865
10     Sports & Outdoors  0.006030
0   Automotive & Gadgets  0.000412
```

and I would like, for example, to extract the 'cat' of the first line.
When I do:

```
cluster_ordre['cluster0']['cat'][7]
```

the output is

```
Home Appliances
```

Exactly what I was looking for, because I knew that the index was 7.
Lets say I don't know this index, so I tried:

```
cluster_ordre['cluster0']['cat'][0:1]
```

the output is now:

```
7    Home Appliances
Name: cat
```

Without knowing the index of the first line, how can I exactly get "Home Appliances"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values` property represents the underlying array. So I can just do:

```
cluster_ordre['cluster0']['cat'].values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all rows that match a particular value I would do the following:

```
df = cluster_ordre['cluster0']
df.loc[df['cat'] == 'Home Appliances','cat']
```

or

```
df[df['cat'] == 'Home Appliances']
```

Here we take a reference to the a data frame from your dict of dataframes.
We then use `loc` to perform label indexing to find where the column 'cat' has the value that matches 'Home Applicances' or just to do plain boolean indexing (second example).